# regex find and replace with preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

I'm kind of staring blind on this one, trying to use preg_match_all to find texts placed in between hashes

```
##START of the text##
the text <b>starts</b> here etc
##END of the the text##
##START of the text 2##
Other version stringtext <b>starts</b> here etc
##END of the the text 2##
```

whatever I try, one time I get `of the text` and other time only between hashes, can anybody help me with the regex?

Comment: So are you trying to capture `START of the text` or `the text <b>starts</b> here etc`?

Comment: Please can you post some of your attempts...

Comment: @nickb trying to capture `the text <b>starts</b> here etc` and `Other version strinttext ...`

Comment: @Lix I've tried f.e. `preg_match_all("/(##START[.*]+##)(.*)(##END[.*]+##)/i", $txt, $matches);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = '##START of the text##
the text <b>starts</b> here etc
##END of the the text##
##START of the text 2##
Other version stringtext <b>starts</b> here etc
##END of the the text 2##';

preg_match_all('/##START.+?##[\n](.+?)##END/s', $string, $matches);
// look for any characters between ##START and ##END, 's' will make it match newlines as well

print_r($matches[1]);
```

Will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => the text <b>starts</b> here etc

    [1] => Other version stringtext <b>starts</b> here etc

)
```

Comment: thnx, helps me a lot, but how do I get only `the text <b>starts</b> here etc` and `Other version stringtext <b>starts</b> here etc` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '##START of the text##
the text <b>starts</b> here etc
##END of the the text##
##START of the text 2##
Other version stringtext <b>starts</b> here etc
##END of the the text 2##';

preg_match_all( '~##(.+)##~', $str, $matches );
```

print_r( $matches ) yield to :

```
Array ( [0] => START of the text [1] => END of the the text [2] => START of the text 2 [3] => END of the the text 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so good with regex but here is my solution, i'm not matching lines starts with a hash,^ is for line-start, (?!#) is negative lookahead looking for # character, m modifier for multi-line.

```
$string = <<<EOD
##START of the text##
the text <b>starts</b> here etc
##END of the the text##
##START of the text 2##
Other version stringtext <b>starts</b> here etc
##END of the the text 2##
EOD;

preg_match_all('~^(?!#).*~m',$string,$match);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($match);
```

as i said i'm new to regex so an expert warn me if i'm wrong.